# bash: apktool: command not found

Tags: android, bash, git-bash, apktool

I just installed apktool with the guide on here https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/.

I have a bash script that runs apktool but whenever I run the bash script on git-bash it will say that it cannot find the command apktool. Running apktool on cmd works fine though. I'm using Windows.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check the following to ensure the problem doesn't lie with your procedure:

1. Ensure Openjdk (Java) version is > 1.8
2. You have renamed the jar file (apktool.jar)
3. You have root/admin access to `C://Windows` (If you just copied them to `C://Windows`) 
    OR 
    You defined the PATH environment variables correctly and made it available to all users (If the files are in some other folder)
4. Open command prompt in admin just to make sure cmd gets right to execute the apktool file